# Unable to incorporate Eclispe JDT codeAssist facilities outside a Plug-in

Tags: java, eclipse, code-completion, eclipse-jdt

Using Eclipse jdt facilities, you can traverse the AST of java code snippets as follows:

```
ASTParser ASTparser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS3);
ASTparser.setSource("package x;class X{}".toCharArray());
ASTparser.createAST(null).accept(...);
```

But when trying to perform code complete & code selection it seems that I have to do it in a plug-in application since I have to write codes like

```
IFile file = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getFile(new Path(somePath));
ICodeAssist i  = JavaCore.createCompilationUnitFrom(f);
i.codeComplete/codeSelect(...)
```

Is there anyway that I can finally get a stand-alone java application which incorporates the jdt code complete/select facilities?

thx a lot!
shi kui

---

I have noticed it that using org.eclipse.jdt.internal.codeassist.complete.CompletionParser
I can parse a code snippet as well.

```
CompletionParser parser =new CompletionParser(new ProblemReporter(
        DefaultErrorHandlingPolicies.proceedWithAllProblems(),
        new CompilerOptions(null),
        new DefaultProblemFactory(Locale.getDefault())),
        false);
org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.batch.CompilationUnit sourceUnit =
new org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.batch.CompilationUnit(
    "class T{f(){new T().=1;}  \nint j;}".toCharArray(), "testName", null);
CompilationResult compilationResult = new CompilationResult(sourceUnit, 0, 0, 0);
CompilationUnitDeclaration unit = parser.dietParse(sourceUnit, compilationResult, 25);
```

But I have 2 questions:
 1. How to retrive the assist information?
 2. How can I specify  class path or source path for the compiler to look up type/method/field information?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so, unless you provide your own implementation of [`ICodeAssist`](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/jdt/core/ICodeAssist.java.htm).

As the [Performing code assist on Java code](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/index.cgi/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/guide/jdt_api_codeassist.htm?view=co) mentions,  Elements that allow this manipulation should implement ICodeAssist.

> There are two kinds of manipulation:
>
> - **Code completion** - compute the completion of a Java token.
> - **Code selection** - answer the Java element indicated by the selected text of a given offset and length.
>
> In the Java model there are two elements that implement this interface: `IClassFile` and `ICompilationUnit`.
>   Code completion and code selection only answer results for a class file if it has attached source.

You could try opening a File [outside of any workspace](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform/msg56366.html) (like [this FAQ](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_open_an_editor_on_a_file_outside_the_workspace%3F)), but the result wouldn't implement `ICodeAssist`.

So the `IFile` [most of the time](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.tools/msg56227.html) comes [from a workspace location](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform/msg56731.html).